# Cassandra. describe keyspace. Syntax error

Tags: cassandra

I followed [this Tutorial](http://www.hjort.co/2010/09/talking-to-cassandra-using-java-and-dao.html) and managed to create 'ContactsList' keyspace at the server with cassandra-cli. However, when I am trying to describe the following keyspace, I am getting strange error:

```
[default@unknown] describe keyspace ContactList; 
Syntax error at position 9: no viable alternative at input 'keyspace'
```

I am using Apache Cassandra 1.1 [(Documentation of "describe keyspace" is here)](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/DESCRIBE)

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Those docs are for CQL, which you can use on the command line with cqlsh.

If you want to use cassandra-cli, the syntax is `describe <keyspacename>;` i.e. without the 'keyspace'.